# Cannot connect to Azure Sql Database with whitelisted IP

Tags: sql, azure, ms-access

I have linked tables in an access database connected to a web app. I have whitelisted my IP on my laptop and my desktop. My laptop can connect. My desktop with the same settings states I need to whitelist my IP I have done this for the past day and receive the same error.

I have even turned off my firewall on the desktop. I just don't understand. It is a simple access database that I have spent more time troubleshooting my connection than I did building it.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. you mention SQL Database, but you also mention a "web app." What, specifically, are you trying to connect to? SQL Database Service offers IP whitelisting in its firewall. Web Apps don't (though Virtual Machines do). Please edit to clarify.

Comment: apologies. I am trying to connect to Sql Database Service. I am already successfully connected on my laptop but on my desktop (sitting next to me) I cannot connect. I whitelisted my IP (desktop on laptop have same whitelisted client due to be on same router). I continue to receive the "add client IP  to azure message".

Comment: When Access cannot connect, do you have the exact error message? Are you positive that it's an Azure SQL firewall issue? And also, are you using the exact same connection string and credentials to connect to the Azure SQL database from Access as you are from SQL Server Management Studio on your desktop?

Comment: Connection failed:
SQLState: '42000'
SQL Server Error: 40615
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open server '******r' requested by the login. Client with IP address '*********' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.

Comment: That is the exact error message I receive. I have checked that I am using the same string and creds. I am beyond stumped.

Comment: At this point I even copied the .dsn from the laptop to the desktop and now I am told my "there are no object names in that database.

Comment: Definition of insanity . Doing the same thing over and over. I think this is going to be straw that make pay an outrageous fortune for a simple data for the support for AZURE. Thanks for taking something simplistic like linking tables and turn it in to a nightmare Microsoft.

Comment: @HeatherHitchler - First: You included *zero* code or additional info in your question. And then you buried your error statement in a comment. As far as firewall settings, pretty simple to do, but not sure what you expect as an answer when you've provided no specific details from your desktop. Not sure where anything was turned into a nightmare. Also not sure how you equate support with costing "a fortune" (just look at the Developer level plan), though I don't see why you'd even need support for this, since (without details) it seems like a config error or coding error.